# Python: problems with implementation of external module

Tags: python, python-import

**Update: I just realized that in my Python 3.4 the win32com package is missing which comport is referencing to.
The module before was used in a Python 2.7 environment.**

I try to call a method out of a module and encounter the following problems:

```
import sys, serial
from external_source import  comport

class Controllerboard:
    def __init__(self):
        self.DUT_COMPORT = None

    def find_Comport(self):            
        comports = comport.scan_ports()
   .
   .
   .
```

In another module i call:

```
CBoard = Controllerboard()
CBoard.find_Comport()
```

Executing the script I get: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'comport' referenced before assignment`

If i place `comport = None` before comports =...,
I get: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'scan_ports'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Executing the script I get: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'comport' referenced before assignment" - the code you've posted shows nothing that would cause that effect. We can guess at the parts you haven't shown - for example, maybe you've accidentally assigned to `comport` instead of `comports` somewhere - but without an MCVE, we can't do much else to help you.

Comment: Please defince MCVE.
Before the find_Comport-code wasn't inside a class definition. Due to implementation in my own workspace i generated a class and integrated the code.

Comment: An MCVE is [enough of the code to reproduce the problem, and no more code than that](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If it is in the same folder as your script try to import the module via:
from . import comport

Comment: Doesn't improve. I assume  that dot means the same as the name of the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `find_Comport()` does a scan and then does nothing with the result. They remain in the scope of this function, and are discarded after it is finished. You don't even save them as an attribute of `self`.

You have either to save them anywhere, or to *return* your found values at the end of the function. And then in the main script call

```
comports = CBoard.find_Comport()
```

so the returned output is then accessible in this new variable.

Comment: Sorry for not making that clear. It's only a snippet of code.
But that's the line where the error occurs, so it wasn't necessary to post the rest.

Comment: @Creatronik: "that's the line where the error occurs, so it wasn't necessary to post the rest" - that's like trying to investigate a murder by only looking at the bullet hole. We need more context than that. Heck, you didn't even post the whole error message - you took out the stack trace.

Comment: Ok, sorry! 
If i had posted the rest of the code it would've been obvious, because there was a variable with the same name of the module i tried to use.